Transaction Performance Analysis Overview report compared to a script for lock statistics
In SQL server for a specific database I used the standard reports to gather table analysis from the transaction performance analysis overview report. Which gave me the lock statistics.
Some of the databases  couldn't access this report so I used a script as follows
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
    OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS TableName,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.page_lock_count), 0) AS PageLockCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(s.page_lock_wait_count), 0) AS PageLockWaitCount,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(s.page_lock_wait_count) > 0 
        THEN ISNULL(SUM(s.page_lock_wait_in_ms), 0) / NULLIF(SUM(s.page_lock_wait_count), 0) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS AvgWaitTimePerLockWait_ms
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS s
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions AS p ON s.object_id = p.object_id AND s.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    p.index_id <= 1
    AND p.object_id > 100  
    AND s.page_lock_count > 0  
GROUP BY 
    OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id);

I compared the results from my script to the SQL report for those I could access, for fact checking.
However I found some discrepancies on the SQL report and from the script data. Keep in mind I did run both of these reports at the same time.
For example the SQL report shows me the following
Table name       |   PageLockCount | PageLockWaitCount | AvgWaitTimePerLockWait_ms
Table1           | 2414137869      | 139               | 1321.81
Table2           | 28675664        | 167               | 9405.07

and results from my script are
Table name       |   PageLockCount | PageLockWaitCount | AvgWaitTimePerLockWait_ms
Table1           | 35310018        | 0                 | 0
Table2           | 84876           | 0                 | 0

Should my script results not be at a closer range to the SQL standard report?
I am basically trying to write a script that would show me the PageLockCount, PageLockWaitCount, AvgWaitTimePerLockWait_ms and headblockers for each table in a database.
Can someone provide clarification if I am going about this in the correct manner?

Try using SQL Profiler to capture the queries generated by the report.
